# Fixtures не загружают данные?

Tags: php, yii2, codeception

```
class CustomerFixture extends ActiveFixture
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Customer\Customer';
}

class AreaFixture extends ActiveFixture
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Data\Area\Areas';
    public $depends = ['app\tests\fixtures\CustomerFixture'];
}
```

customer.php

```
return [
  'customer' => ['id'=> 1]
];
```

area.php

```
return
 [
    [
        'id'=>'a10','update_at' => 2,'create_at' => 1,'customer_id' =>1,
        'summary' => 's1','description'=>'d1','color'=>'c1',
        'favourite'=>'1'
    ],
     [
         'id'=>'a2','update_at' => 2,'create_at' => 1,'customer_id' =>1,
         'summary' => 's2','description'=>'d2','color'=>'c2',
         'favourite'=>'0'
     ],
     [
         'id'=>'a4','update_at' => 1,'create_at' => 1,'customer_id' =>1,
         'summary' => 's4','description'=>'d4','color'=>'c4',
         'favourite'=>'1'
     ]
];
```

Тест-кейс

```
 class SynchronizationTest extends TestCase

      public function fixtures()
        {
            return [
                CustomerFixture::className(),
                AreaFixture::className(),
            ];
        }
 public function testSynchronization(){

}
```

Возникает такая проблема в только созданной базе, также с таблице area если в ручную создать запись в customer.
В чем проблема не понятно?
Такое ощущение что 2 раза вызывается инициализация.
Метод тестовый пустой.
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `customer` (`id`) VALUES (1)

Comment: Добрый день. А зачем Вам два return?

Comment: Нет, отдельные, один для CustomerFixture, второй для AreaFixture

Comment: Так оформите код так, чтобы это было понятно!

Comment: У Вас дублируется id для customer. Думаю, что не надо принудительно устанавливать id

Comment: База пустая. Если не устанавливать то ошибка с area такая же, но у area точно нужно устанавливать.

Comment: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' дублируется id.

Comment: я понял, но как если в базе пусто и дубликатов в массивах у меня нет.

Comment: В базу пишется с дубликатом.